# is there any way to initialize dynamically created 2D array

Tags: c++

```
#define ROWS 5
#define COLUMNS 5

int main(void)
{
    bool *p = new bool[ROWS * COLUMNS] = {
        {false, true, false, true, true},
        {true, false, true, false, true},
        {false, true, false, false, false},
        {true, false, false, false, true},
        {true, true, false, true, false}
    };
}

// [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with std=c++11 or-std=gnu++11
// [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

What is the problem here and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post images, and instead include all relevant information in the question as text.

Comment: Just remove `{` and `}` in every subarray, because you defined your array as completely flat

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Well, that's not enough, but since C++11 you can remove the offending `=` and use a brace enclosed initializer: https://godbolt.org/z/nsv63GPaj

Comment: What do you think a "2D array" is?

Answer (score 1):

What you have trying to do is define a one-dimension array and initialized it like a two-dimension array, in that case, you should choose one of the following:

One-Dimention array:

```
  bool bool_arr[ROWS * COLUMNS] = {
      false, true, false, true, true,
      true, false, true, false, true,
      false, true, false, false, false,
      true, false, false, false, true,
      true, true, false, true, false
  };
```

Two-Dimention array:

```
bool bool_mat[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {
      {false, true, false, true, true},
      {true, false, true, false, true},
      {false, true, false, false, false},
      {true, false, false, false, true},
      {true, true, false, true, false}
  };
```